# How to build tensorflow_gpu environment in windows 10？

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I'm using windows10，gtx1650ti, but since windows native GPUs are not supported after tensorflow 2.10, I'm going to install python 3.9, tensorflow 2.10, cuda=12.0, cudnn=8.9.7 environment.
But I can't find cuda=12.0 in anaconda official website.
how should I install the libraries？
how should I finish building this environment？

It took me a whole day to go from installing cuda to installing and finding out that TF doesn't recognize the GPU to finding out that windows is not supported after tenforflow 2.10.
[I tried using pip but it didn't work either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U20dH.png)

Comment: Tensorflow 2.10 is not compatibe with cuda 12. Did you take a look at [the official installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native)?

Comment: It looks like they want you to use WSL2 for higher versions of tensorflow. "How should I install the libraries" [cuda-toolkit](https://anaconda.org/nvidia/cuda-toolkit) it looks like conda has it. You need to install the correct cudatoolkit for the tensorflow which appears to be 11.8.

Comment: This set of packages worked for me (win10): `python 3.9`, `cudatoolkit=11.2`, `cudnn=8.1.0`, `python -m pip install "tensorflow<2.11"`